# How to disable user in Asp.NET Identity MVC5

Tags: asp.net, .net, identity, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I try to disable any existing user using:

```
IdentityResult confirmUserResult = await UserManager.SetConfirmedAsync(userId, confirm);
```

This identity result returns `Succeed = true`. However, after I 'disable' the user, I try to login with the related user and I can do it.

So, my question is how can I disable a user's account?

Note: I use ASP.Net MVC5 Identity.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer, which explains how to override the `PasswordSignInAsync` function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35293561/2908623