# How to disable a User in Identity 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I'm trying to find a way to disable a user in Identity 2.0 and can't seem to find any info on it.

I would like to basically set a user to IsActive=false and would prefer to do it as soon as the user is created. However, I need a way to set the IsActive for our site Admin. I already have this with ASP.Net membership but I'm looking to covert the site to MVC and Identity.

For my requirements we ask people to go ahead and register an account but we want it to be disabled by default. Then when we receive payment for joining we will go back and enable them. We also use it to disable users when their subscription is up and they haven't renewed.

Is there a way to disable an account without deleting it or only locking them out for an X amount of time? So far I haven't found any way of just disabling a user in Identity and I'm surprised this question hasn't come up before.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you create a site with the Identity bits installed, your site will have a file called "IdentityModels.cs". In this file is a class called ApplicationUser which inherits from IdentityUser.

```
// You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
```

There is a nice link in the comments there, for ease click [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594)

This tutorial tells you exactly what you need to do to add custom properties for your user.

And actually, don't even bother looking at the tutorial.

1) add a property to the ApplicationUser class, eg:

```
public bool? IsEnabled { get; set; }
```

2) add a column with the same name on the AspNetUsers table in your DB.

3) boom, that's it!

Now in your AccountController, you have a Register action as follows:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, IsEnabled = true };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
```

I've added the IsEnabled = true on the creation of the ApplicationUser object. The value will now be persisted in your new column in the AspNetUsers table.

You would then need to deal with checking for this value as part of the sign in process, by overriding PasswordSignInAsync in ApplicationSignInManager.

I did it as follows:

```
public override Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, bool shouldLockout)
    {
        var user = UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(userName).Result;

        if ((user.IsEnabled.HasValue && !user.IsEnabled.Value) || !user.IsEnabled.HasValue)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<SignInStatus>(SignInStatus.LockedOut);
        }

        return base.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, rememberMe, shouldLockout);
    }
```

Your mileage may vary, and you may not want to return that SignInStatus, but you get the idea.

Comment: How do you achieve the same in ASP.NET Core 1.0 with Identity 3.0 that does not have ApplicationSignInManager or PasswordSignInAsync(...)?

Comment: Using `.Result` is against recommendations and is known to cause deadlocks in certain scenarios, it also blocks the thread defeating the whole point of asynchrony. It would be better to mark the `PasswordSignInAsync` method as `async` and to await `FindByEmailAsync` instead.

Comment: The biggest problem with this is if they're already logged in, it won't affect them. Particularly if they checked the Remember Me checkbox. If they access the site on a regular basis, they will never need to log in. I'm trying to figure out if the existing lockout logic can be used for this, and if it is any better at handling users who are already logged in.

Answer (score 8):

Was doing some research on this and turns out the `IdentityUser` base class has some properties related to this topic. Namely: `LockoutEnabled` and `LockoutEndDateUtc`.

It's sufficient to set `LockoutEnabled` to `true` and `LockoutEndDateUtc` to some future date in order for the standard `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` to pick it up and act accordingly without any overrides or customizations.

And if you want to just disable the user without specifying any exact date of reactivation you can just set it to `DateTime.MaxValue`.

Comment: it is confusing that docs, says "Gets or sets a flag indicating if the user **could** be locked out."; why "could"? mmhh

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Create a custom user store that implements IUserLockoutStore.

```
     public Task<DateTimeOffset> GetLockoutEndDateAsync(MyUser user)
    {
        //..
    }

    public Task SetLockoutEndDateAsync(MyUser user, DateTimeOffset lockoutEnd)
    {
        //..
    }

    public Task<int> IncrementAccessFailedCountAsync(MyUser user)
    {
        //..
    }

    public Task ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(MyUser user)
    {
        //..
    }

    public Task<int> GetAccessFailedCountAsync(MyUser user)
    {
        //..
    }

    public Task<bool> GetLockoutEnabledAsync(MyUser user)
    {
        //..
    }

    public Task SetLockoutEnabledAsync(MyUser user, bool enabled)
    {
        //..
    }
}
```

Step #2: Instead of UserManager, use the following class in your login/logout actions, passing it an instance of your custom user store.

```
    public class LockingUserManager<TUser, TKey> : UserManager<TUser, TKey>
    where TUser : class, IUser<TKey> 
    where TKey : IEquatable<TKey> 
{
    private readonly IUserLockoutStore<TUser, TKey> _userLockoutStore;

    public LockingUserManager(IUserLockoutStore<TUser, TKey> store)
        : base(store)
    {
        if (store == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("store");

        _userLockoutStore = store;
    }

    public override async Task<TUser> FindAsync(string userName, string password)
    {
        var user = await FindByNameAsync(userName);

        if (user == null) return null;

        var isUserLockedOut = await GetLockoutEnabled(user);

        if (isUserLockedOut) return user;

        var isPasswordValid = await CheckPasswordAsync(user, password);

        if (isPasswordValid)
        {
            await _userLockoutStore.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user);
        }
        else
        {
            await IncrementAccessFailedCount(user);

            user = null;
        }

        return user;
    }

    private async Task<bool> GetLockoutEnabled(TUser user)
    {
        var isLockoutEnabled = await _userLockoutStore.GetLockoutEnabledAsync(user);

        if (isLockoutEnabled == false) return false;

        var shouldRemoveLockout = DateTime.Now >= await _userLockoutStore.GetLockoutEndDateAsync(user);

        if (shouldRemoveLockout)
        {
            await _userLockoutStore.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user);

            await _userLockoutStore.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(user, false);

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private async Task IncrementAccessFailedCount(TUser user)
    {
        var accessFailedCount = await _userLockoutStore.IncrementAccessFailedCountAsync(user);

        var shouldLockoutUser = accessFailedCount > MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout;

        if (shouldLockoutUser)
        {
            await _userLockoutStore.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(user, true);

            var lockoutEndDate = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now + DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan);

            await _userLockoutStore.SetLockoutEndDateAsync(user, lockoutEndDate);
        }
    }
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(string userName, string password)
    {
        var userManager = new LockingUserManager<MyUser, int>(new MyUserStore())
        {
            DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = /* get from appSettings */,
            MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = /* get from appSettings */
        };

        var user = await userManager.FindAsync(userName, password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            // bad username or password; take appropriate action
        }

        if (await _userManager.GetLockoutEnabledAsync(user.Id))
        {
            // user is locked out; take appropriate action
        }

        // username and password are good
        // mark user as authenticated and redirect to post-login landing page
    }
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803109/asp-net-identity-disable-user)

Comment: I might be confused about this or it doesn't address the question. What I take from the code it would be used to see if the user is in a Locked Out state which would have come from unsuccessful login attempts. This looks like it only sets a logout time and the number of failed login attempts before locking them. I'm looking to see if I can just disable the account. Doing something like setting IsActive=false. That way they just can't log in period. When a renewal happens I would just reset IsActive=true. Something similar to that. I'll still look over the code more and see if it will work.

Comment: I wanted to throw out an idea that I'm going to try to implement for disabling a user. I'm going to create a role called something like "NoAccess". Then on my controllers I will not include that role as one that can get to any ActionResult. In my case I will use that as my default role when someone signs up. I think that will take care of my needs.

Comment: However, looks like I might have to either not set Identity to lockout after a certain failed logins or use the code above. I'm surprised Microsoft didn't make it easier to look at someone being locked out and/or an easier way to unlock them.